# Where to add NuGet packages in ASP.NET Core 5 Blazor web-assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I am using .NET 5 SDK version `5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15`, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview - Version 16.8.0 Preview 5.0 . I create solutions ASP.NET Core 5 Blazor web-assembly (options: Authentication/Authorization, Progress web-app).

Where to add NuGet packages (for example, DevExpress Blazor NuGet packages) in ASP.NET Core 5 Blazor web-assembly? `foo.Client` , `foo.Server` or `foo.Shared`?

Comment: those that require the package....

Comment: Let's post your answer. But client `dll` files get from server-side.

Comment: you need to expand on what you trying to ask, but.. for NuGet, the project which will need them are those which have dependency's on them. better question is what design pattern or what is your concern, like why do you want x or y. simply stating which ones, well the answer literally is those which have a dependency. My feeling is your concerned about something or literally have no idea what packages are where and why.... we can help with that. as we don't know which ones your using and why nor do we know ur design.

Comment: exactly, I want add these packages to my solutions https://www.devexpress.com/blazor/

Comment: and what did you discover? sounds like a UI comp so add to …client?... but again if you want to use something from it in server or shared you will have to add accordingly

Comment: if something in Client using the nuget package, then u will add there , also if something in Server is using the nuget package then add there, and then if something in Shared is using the nuget package then add in there....

Answer (score 1):

> Where to add NuGet packages (for example, DevExpress Blazor NuGet packages) in ASP.NET Core 5 Blazor web-assembly? foo.Client , foo.Server or foo.Shared?

A Blazor library would go in the Foo.Client project

A Database package would go in the Server Project.

You would want to avoid adding packages to the Shared project as much as possible.

> But client dll files get from server-side.

Yes, but that doesn't matter - they will end up where the Server expects them, to be served to the client on demand.